# htc one mtp issue

Tags: sync, connection-issues, mtp

Starting two days ago, I've encountered an issue when I wanted to connect my *HTC One* to my PC. In the notification area, appeared a notification that said that MTP mode is active, but it disapeared and appeared again like my device connects and disconnects on and on. Here is what I've tried:

1. modified registry key (issue with Kaspersky Antivirus)
2. installed Microsoft MTP drivers
3. uninstalled antivirus
4. rebooted my phone into safe mode
5. uninstalled *HTC Sync Manager* and HTC drivers, and installed them back

but no success... Did anyone of you encounter and fix this issue with an *HTC One* device with Android 4.3?

Comment: Sounds like either the cable is dodgy or another device is disrupting the USB network.

Comment: I've tried on two computers with 2 cables and still the same result... I've read somewere that it could be the crarger that causes this problem because if it is damaged, the battery does not charges correctly and the phone could not sustain this type of connection (mtp) but it's not quite logic because usb usually returns enough power...